# lebesgue measure of difference of two sets

Tags: measure-theory

Suppose $A,B$ are in $\mathbb R^n$, $A$ lebesgue measurable and $|(A \setminus B)\cup(B\setminus A)| = 0$.  Show $B$ must be lebesgue measurable as well and $|A| = |B|$ (where $|\cdot |$ is the lebesgue outer measure).

Comment: By difference do you mean the symmetric difference $(A\setminus B)\cup(B\setminus A)$ or just $(A\setminus B)$? If the latter, then the claim is trivially false in general, because you can select $B=A\cup X$, where $X$ is a non-measurable set disjoint from $A$.

Comment: If you do mean that $|(A\setminus B)\cup (B\setminus A)|=0$, then you can use monotonicity of the outer measure, and also what you know about sets of zero outer measure

Comment: I'm pretty sure it's the first one.  can you elaborate on the monotonicity and sets of zero outer measure?

Comment: Denoting the symmetric difference by $A\Delta B=(A\setminus B)\cup (B\setminus A)$. Then both $(A\setminus B)$ and $(B\setminus A)$ are subsets of $A\Delta B$. What can you say about their outer measure? Can you find a suitable theorem saying that they are Lebesgue measurable? What do you know about the algebra of Lebesgue measurable sets? Which set you need to subtract from $A$ and which set do you need to add to that set in order to get $B$?

Comment: If everything else fails, draw a Venn diagram.